# C# Calculator Variables not reseting

Tags: c#

The calculartor will run and continue with the same calculation until you type stop then it will begin a new calculation but num1 will remain the last value it was in the previous calculation and not reset.

Example:

Enter a number
22

What calculation do you want to perform
+

Enter a number
33

Answer 55

What calculation do you want to perform
/

Enter a number
5

Answer 11

What calculation do you want to perform
stop

Enter a number
2

What calculation do you want to perform
+

Enter a number
9

Answer 20

```
      Boolean x;
        x = true;

        while (x == true)
        {
            double num1;
            double ans;
            double num2;
            string cal;
            Boolean y;
            y = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number ");
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            while (y == true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("What calculation do you want to perform ");
                cal = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("Enter a number ");
                num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (cal)
                {
                    case "+":
                        ans = add(num1, num2);
                        Console.WriteLine("Answer " + ans);
                        num1 = ans;
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        ans = sub(num1, num2);
                        Console.WriteLine("Answer " + ans);
                        num1 = ans;
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        ans = div(num1, num2);
                        Console.WriteLine("Answer " + ans);
                        num1 = ans;
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        ans = mul(num1, num2);
                        Console.WriteLine("Answer " + ans);
                        num1 = ans;
                        break;

                    case "Stop":
                        y = false;
                        break;
                }


            }
        }
    }

    private static double add(double firstnumber, double secondnumber)
    {
        double answer;
        answer = firstnumber + secondnumber;
        return answer;
    }
    private static double sub(double firstnumber, double secondnumber)
    {
        double answer;
        answer = firstnumber - secondnumber;
        return answer;
    }
    private static double div(double firstnumber, double secondnumber)
    {
        double answer;
        answer = firstnumber / secondnumber;
        return answer;
    }
    private static double mul(double firstnumber, double secondnumber)
    {
        double answer;
        answer = firstnumber * secondnumber;
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: I have two loops so when you enter the first number it goes calc num calc num so you can do 2+2*5+1/7=3

Comment: FYI `while (y == true)` is superfluous. Use `while (y)` instead and rename `y` to something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

just make it zero

```
 case "Stop":
 y = false;
  num1=0;
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The program expects `"Stop"` as input for `cal` in order to terminate, but you typed `"stop"`. See the difference?

It is better to convert the input to lowercase with

```
cal = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
```

and then check for it in the switch statement. Also **always** include a `default` branch in the switch because you need to expect the unexpected.

```
switch (cal)
{
    ..
    case "stop":
        y = false;
        break;
    default:
        // what happens if input is not +-*/ or stop?
        break;
}
```